# Удаление лишнего элемента для парсера

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Есть парсер, считывает цену, но немного некорректно, причиной тому является странная верстка сайта: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я все данные записываю в список:

```
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'b-catalog__item')
    cards = []

    for item in items:
        cards.append(
            {
                'title' : item.find('div', class_='b-catalog__item-title-wrap').get_text(strip = True),
                'link_product': HOST + item.find('div', class_='b-catalog__item-title-wrap').find('a').get('href'),
                'img': HOST + item.find('div', class_='b-catalog__item-wrap').find('a').get('href'),
                'price' : item.find('div', class_='b-catalog__item-price').get_text(strip = True)
            }

        )
    return cards
```

если же поменяю

```
'price' : item.find('div', class_='b-catalog__item-price').get_text(strip = True)
```

на

```
'price' : item.find('span', class_='b-price__num').get_text(strip = True)
```

То особо ничего не поменяется

Суть в том, два варианта:

1. Игнорирование копеек, не знаю, как это реализовать
2. Либо же Сделать разделение копеек, но так, чтобы записывалось в одну колонку файла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно через метод `decompose` удалить тег `sup`.

Пример:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

item = BeautifulSoup("""\
<span class="b-price__num">
    32
    <sup class="sup_cop">59</sup>
<span>
""", "html.parser")

price_el = item.find('span', class_='b-price__num')
price_el.select_one('.sup_cop').decompose()

print(price_el.get_text(strip=True))
# 32
```

---

Использование в коде из вопроса:

```
...
for item in items:
    title_el = item.find('div', class_='b-catalog__item-title-wrap')

    price_el = item.find('span', class_='b-price__num')
    price_el.select_one('.sup_cop').decompose()  # Удаление копеек

    cards.append({
        'title' : title_el.get_text(strip=True),
        'link_product': HOST + title_el.find('a').get('href'),
        'img': HOST + item.find('div', class_='b-catalog__item-wrap').find('a').get('href'),
        'price' : price_el.get_text(strip=True),
    })
return cards
```

Comment: а как можно это реализовать через элемент списка?

Comment: @АлександрПлетнев, а зачем именно через элемент списка? В цикле сделайте переменную для элемента цены и его передавайте в тот словарь. Добавлю пример. Кст, советую избегать дублирования кода, а для получения абсолютных ссылок из относительных использовать специальный метод `from urllib.parse import urljoin`